# Can't access form1 from another class

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a class called class1, in that class i wan;t to write something in a textbox in form1, but it won't let me access Form1.TextBox1.text, another problem is that it won't give me the save dialog in excel, but thats another problem.

How can i acces Form1 controls?

Form1 code

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call ThisDrawing.GetFilepath(True)
    If Me.TextBox1.Text = "" Or Me.TextBox1.Text = "False" Then MsgBox("Er is geen geldige filenaam opgegeven")
End Sub
```

Class1 code

```
Public Shared Sub GetFilepath(ByVal hide As Boolean)
    Dim Xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim Filepath As String
    Call ExcelKoppelen("Z:\test\test.xls")
    Filepath = Xl.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Excel file", "*.xls")
    Form1.TextBox1.text = Filepath

End Sub
```

Excelkoppelen code

```
 Shared Sub ExcelKoppelen(ByVal Bestand As String)
    Dim Xl As Excel.Application
    Dim Filepath As String
    Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Worksheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Worksheet2 As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Xl = GetObject(, "Excel.application")
    If Err.Number Then
        Information.Err.Clear()
        Xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    End If
    Xl.Visible = True
    Xl.ScreenUpdating = True
    Workbook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(Bestand)
    If Err.Number Then
        Workbook = Xl.Workbooks.Open("Z:\test\test.xls")
        Information.Err.Clear()
        Workbook.SaveAs(Bestand)
    End If

    If Err.Number Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0

    Worksheet1 = Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    Worksheet2 = Workbook.Worksheets.Item(2)
    Xl.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the controls in Form1 directly like that, create an object for Form1 as follows and get the controls by using the object.

```
Dim F as New Form1
F.TextBox1.text = Filepath
```